# Optimize code related to Carmichael function in a loop

Tags: python, list, math, primes

I'm working on a project regarding [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). The way I produce outputs for the the Carmichael function works well, but I will be using this function in a loop and for very large inputs. Should I separate the coprimes list and append each new value of n and check if gcd(x, n) == 1 when appending. I want to quickly generate outputs for the Carmichael function. My overall aim is to find when the prime-counting function and the Carmichael function's outputs coincide. I tried Google Collab but the RAM keeps crashing.

How can I optimize the code below? I want to work with very large values of n (such as below).

```
from sympy import primepi
from math import gcd

def carmichael(n):
    coprimes = [x for x in range(1, n) if gcd(x, n) == 1]
    k = 1
    while not all(pow(x, k, n) == 1 for x in coprimes):
        k += 1
    return k

for n in range(10**18, 10**19):
    if primepi(n) == carmichael(n):
        print(n)
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number. An implementation of Korselt's criterion is the only computationally feasible way to determine if numbers on the order of 10\*\*18 are Carmichael numbers.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thank you, I had missed that. I will try to implement that in my code.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Sorry, I meant Carmichael function.

Comment: Read further into the wikipedia article where it has [algorithms to compute the Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Computing_%CE%BB(n)_with_Carmichael's_theorem).

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Indeed, the method with Euler's totient function seems more efficient. I will try it. Thank you!